# Want to copy rows based on input of a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code that I've been using (not mine). It works well with me because I know that I can change the value in `sh.Rows ("x")` to whatever row I want and it'll grab everything that I need. I want to make this easier for one of my co workers to use so that they wouldn't have to go into Visual Basics to edit it. Is there an easy way to make it so that it can take whatever row that's in cell B2 from every sheet and paste it into a master sheet?

```
Sub CopytoMaster()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim DestSh As Worksheet
    Dim Last As Long
    If SheetExists("Master") = True Then
        MsgBox "The sheet Master already exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set DestSh = Worksheets.Add
    DestSh.Name = "Master"
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sh.Name <> DestSh.Name Then
            If sh.UsedRange.Count > 1 Then
                Last = LastRow(DestSh)
                sh.Rows("7").Copy DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, 1)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub CheckMaster()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim DestSh As Worksheet
    Dim Last As Long
    If SheetExists("Master") = True Then
        MsgBox "The sheet Master already exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set DestSh = Worksheets.Add
    DestSh.Name = "Master"
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sh.Name <> DestSh.Name Then
            If sh.UsedRange.Count > 1 Then
                Last = LastRow(DestSh)
                With sh.Rows("7")
                    DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, 1).Resize(.Rows.Count, _
                    .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
                End With
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Function Lastcol(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    Lastcol = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Column
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
Function SheetExists(SName As String, _
                     Optional ByVal WB As Workbook) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    If WB Is Nothing Then Set WB = ThisWorkbook
    SheetExists = CBool(Len(Sheets(SName).Name))
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `Range.Value` method to grab the value of B2. Place this within the `.Row()` method. In other words, you would just need to change your `sh.Rows("7")` to `sh.Rows(ws.range("B2").value)`.

```
Sub CopytoMaster()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim DestSh As Worksheet
    Dim Last As Long
    If SheetExists("Master") = True Then
        MsgBox "The sheet Master already exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set DestSh = Worksheets.Add
    DestSh.Name = "Master"
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sh.Name <> DestSh.Name Then
            If sh.UsedRange.Count > 1 Then
                Last = LastRow(DestSh)
                sh.Rows(ws.Range("B2").Value).Copy DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, 1)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Same thing with your second procedure:

```
Sub CheckMaster()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    ...

    With sh.Rows(ws.Range("B2").Value)
        DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, 1).Resize(.Rows.Count, _
        .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
    End With
```

Where `ws` is the worksheet object that contains the value in question. You weren't clear on if this was the same worksheet as `sh` or not, so if it is you can change `ws` to `sh` - otherwise, you will need to **Set** `ws` to the sheet that contains the value.

Comment: Sorry about that, I was trying to grab X row from what was input into cell B2 from every sheet in the current workbook that is open and paste it into a master sheet.

Comment: So, it would need to be the `B2` in each sheet?

Comment: In the cell B2 would be the row I type in that I want copied over from each sheet.

Comment: I get that... But what I am asking is which sheet is cell B2 located in? Every sheet in your workbook has a `B2` cell... So which B2 are you asking about?... _Side note: my answer says that if you are using the `B2` from each sheet then all you need to do is change the `ws.` to `sh.`._

Comment: Ohhhhhhh gotcha. I was hoping to use B2 from a sheet Labeled "Main"

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have now and it is working pretty much how I want it to.

```
Sub CopytoMaster2()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim DestSh As Worksheet
Dim mainSh As Worksheet

Dim Last As Long
If SheetExists("Master") = True Then
    MsgBox "The sheet Master already exist"
    Exit Sub
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set DestSh = Worksheets.Add
DestSh.Name = "Master"

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set mainSh = wb.Sheets("Main")

For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If sh.Name <> mainSh.Name And sh.Name <> DestSh.Name Then
        If sh.UsedRange.Count > 1 Then
            Last = LastRow(DestSh)
            sh.Rows(mainSh.Range("E7").Value).Copy DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, 1)
        End If
    End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

Sub CheckMaster2()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim DestSh As Worksheet
    Dim mainSh As Worksheet
    Dim Last As Long
    If SheetExists("Master") = True Then
        MsgBox "The sheet Master already exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set DestSh = Worksheets.Add
    DestSh.Name = "Master"
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set mainSh = wb.Sheets("Main")

```
For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If mainSh.Name <> sh.Name And sh.Name <> DestSh.Name Then
        If sh.UsedRange.Count > 1 Then
            Last = LastRow(DestSh)
            With sh.Rows(mainSh.Range("E7").Value)
                DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, 1).Resize(.Rows.Count, _
                .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
            End With
        End If
    End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

Function LastRow2(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Function Lastcol2(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    Lastcol = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Column
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
Function SheetExists2(SName As String, _
                     Optional ByVal wb As Workbook) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    SheetExists = CBool(Len(Sheets(SName).Name))
End Function